# Batch Files - Prevent Output of Variable Values

Tags: batch-file

Right now I'am currently working on a batch file that at a certain time during a certain day it will automatically shutdown the user's PC. So far I have accomplished this. Now i'm coding a standalone version that launches at startup and keeps going until certain values are reached.

```
:Loop
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:,. " %%A in ("%time%") do (
set "Hour=%%A"
set "Min=%%B"

)

set /a Hour = Hour %% 12
if %Hour%==0 set "Hour=12"
set "Allm=%Hour%:%Min%"
echo %Allm%
cls
if %Allm% equ %_input% (goto:Continue) else goto:Loop
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 GOTO Loop

:Continue
for /f %%a in ('date /t') do set DAY=%%a
IF %DAY% equ %S% (goto:shutdown) else goto:Loop

:shutdown
echo @echo off &setlocal >>PMLite.bat
echo :Loop >>PMLite.bat
echo for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:,. " %%A in ("%time%") do ( >>PMLite.bat
echo  set "Hour=%%A" >>PMLite.bat
echo  set "Hour=%%B" >>PMLite.bat
echo echo. >>PMLite.bat
echo ) >>PMLite.bat
echo echo. >>PMLite.bat
echo set /a Hour = Hour %% 12 >>PMLite.bat
echo if %Hour%==0 set "Hour=12" >>PMLite.bat
echo echo. >>PMLite.bat
echo set "Allm=%Hour%:%Min%" >>PMLite.bat
echo echo. >>PMLite.bat
echo echo %Allm% >>PMLite.bat
echo IF %Allm%==9:20 GOTO timereached >>PMLite.bat
echo IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 GOTO Loop >>PMLite.bat
echo :timereached >>PMLite.bat
echo for /f %%a in ('date /t') do set DAY=%%a >>PMLite.bat
echo IF %DAY% equ %S% (goto:shutdown) else goto:Loop >>PMLite.bat
echo :shutdown >>PMLite.bat
echo pause >>PMLite.bat
echo shutdown.exe -s -f -t 00 >>PMLite.bat
```

My main goal is to have the program generate a batch file file called "PMLite.bat" that monitors the PC's current date/time and when the values of the variables created by the user are meet than shutdown their pc. Pay attention specifically to line #340 which has the following code `echo IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 GOTO Loop >>PMLite.bat` which should execute a value of 0 if the time is not meet with what the user requested to go back to checking the time until it's met. But because im outputting to a generated .bat I get the following result in PMLite.bat `IF 0 EQU 0 GOTO Loop` because its outputting the value of errorlevel into the script rendering it useless. Is there a way to output to the generated script while still keeping %errorlevel% in the script?

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image.  Copy and paste the code into your question and create a code block of it.

Comment: Either double the percentage signs %%errorlevel%% or escape them with carets ^%errorlevel^%

Comment: Note that date command highly depends on locale. It's better to use wmic which is locale-independent

Comment: Please read this help topic: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @Richard It actually freaking worked! I really appreciate the help guys. Learning from the wise makes learning to code easier. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard mentioned in the comments already you have to escape the percentage signs in order to make them printable with `echo` using them twice: `%%errorlevel%%`.
As your script is right now, your `PMLite.bat` will grow larger and larger as you are only appending text at the end of the file.
Something to probably make your script a bit more readable/shorter:

You can append blocks of text using the redirection operator only once:

```
>yourfile.bat (
echo line one
echo line two
echo line three
)
```

With that the content of `yourfile.bat` will get replaced with everything contained within the block of parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you @geisterfurz007 for informing me of an easier way to replace contents of a file. I knew there had to be a simpler way. Learning from the wise makes learning to code easier. Have a nice day!

Comment: Well that was a nice comment :) Thanks a lot and wishing you the same!